# How to prevent my code from rewriting values in the same index numbers in the following code

Tags: java

```
package javaapplication5;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("please enter the number of test cases: ");
        int T=input.nextInt();
        int c=T*2;
        int[] data=new int[c];
        for(int i=T; i>0; i--){
            for (int j=0;j<=i-1;j++){
                data[]=input.nextInt();  
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<c; i++){
            System.out.println(data[]);  
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to print the sum of 2 numbers provided by the user. We want to take input and print numbers in this sample format:

```
Input
3 
1 2
100 200
10 40

Output
3
300
50
```

We'll first ask the user to enter the number of test cases. In the above sample, it's 3. Then in the next lines, the user will enter numbers as shown, and then the out would be shown as shown in the sample.
In the above-mentioned incomplete code, I've declared an array to store the numbers entered by the user. in my code, each time the inner loop gets executed the values in the index variables are rewritten. I want my program to store values in different index numbers. for example, if the user enters the value of test cases as 3 then my code should store 6 values (taken from the user) in 6 index variables in the array.

Comment: Your code does not compile -> [mre]

Comment: `data[] = input.nextInt()` does not compile.

Comment: Did you mean `for (int j=0;j<=i-1;j++){
                data[j]=input.nextInt();  
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the input given, if you give number of test cases as 3, then an array of 3*2 = 6 must be created and we need to store 6 values in it.

Then the numbers will get added in pairs

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("please enter the number of test cases: ");
        int T=input.nextInt();
        int c=T*2;
        int[] data=new int[c];
        for (int i=0; i<c; i++) {
            data[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i=0; i<c; i+=2){
            System.out.println(data[i] + data[i + 1]);  
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces the output according to the input given :

Input :

```
3 
1 2
100 200
10 40
```

Output:

```
3
300
50
```